# Dismiss a UIAlertController while Loading a TableView

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview, uialertcontroller

I programmed an `UIAlertController` as a Loading Screen

```
let waitActivityAlert = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: "Please wait...\n", preferredStyle: .alert)
let spinner = UIActivityIndicatorView(activityIndicatorStyle: UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.whiteLarge)

func letsspin(){

    spinner.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    waitActivityAlert.view.addSubview(spinner)


    let xConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: spinner, attribute: .centerX, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: waitActivityAlert.view, attribute: .centerX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)

    let yConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: spinner, attribute: .centerY, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: waitActivityAlert.view, attribute: .centerY, multiplier: 1.4, constant: 0)

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([ xConstraint, yConstraint])

    spinner.isUserInteractionEnabled = false


    spinner.color = UIColor.black

    spinner.startAnimating()
    let height: NSLayoutConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: waitActivityAlert.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.height, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 100)

    waitActivityAlert.view.addConstraints([height])

    present(waitActivityAlert, animated: true)


}
```

and I'm loading a TableViewController in the background. While my `UITableView` is loading the cells, I am closing this `UIAlertController` with the following function:

```
func letsstopspin(){

    spinner.stopAnimating()
    self.waitActivityAlert.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

And the `UIAlertController` doesn't dismiss and I am getting this message in the console:

> Attempt to dismiss from view controller  while
>   a presentation or dismiss is in progress

So i don't know know how to solve the problem. Is there any method that can be called after the `tableView()` Methods? 
I attempted everything but the `UIAlertController` doesn't dismiss whatever I try.

Comment: Are you calling letstopspin() from the background thread?  You should make all of your UI calls to the main thread

Comment: Yes I am calling letsstopspin() at the end of a function that is used before the TableView is filling the cells

Comment: If you are making the call from a background thread, then it won't be called until the background thread finishes.  You need to wrap it in a dispatch to the main queue

Comment: Can you tell me an example for that? My main queue (viewDidLoad()) calls the function which starts the tableView after the letsspin() method, so after the tableView is filled with data my is function finished. I'm pretty new in the programming world so I don't know how to wrap the letsstopspin() in there. If I am wrapping it at the end it doesn't start at all.

Comment: have a look at the answer I posted - if you call self.stopActivityIndicator() at any point, the indicator should stop straight away.

Comment: Thats the point, the activity indicator stops if i call spinner.stopAnimating() but the dismiss of the waitActivityAlert doesn't work! I get the warning in the console but the waitActivityAlert is still in the foreground.

Comment: dismiss your alert in the same place - it's just another UI call, so if you call from within a background queue it will be delayed, so put it in the main queue

Comment: I will try that, thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one I prepared earlier.  If you only make the call from one place, then you don't need a separate function, but if you think you might ever need to call it again you should do this - and a similar one for `startActivityIndicator`

```
func stopActivityIndicator()
{
    DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
        self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
    })
}
```

Comment: I added 
`override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        self.letsstopspin()
        
    }`
 and now it is dismissed but im still getting the "Attempt to dismiss from view controller while presentation or dismiss is in progress" warning.

Comment: I forgot to delete the call in the other function :D it works now without any problems, Thank you very much!